# Ubuntu 22.04 Intel Wireless-AC 9260. No wireless devices after upgrade from 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, iwlwifi

I've struggled with this issue for some time and afaik, something went awry during the Ubuntu upgrade. I saw some errors upon the first boot pertaining to `iwlwifi` but wasn't able to capture them. Upon subsequent reboot, I haven't found them using `sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi`. I have tried a number of instructions provided on the internet to no avail.

I have added all relevant configuration information to https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/nhJWMtGQ76/ following https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info execution

My wireless card is a bluetooth and wifi combined card shipped with the ASUS TUF Gaming x570 plus wifi motherboard. I can see this device listed for what I believe is bluetooth operation, but not for wireless connection. For example these produce output `sudo lsusb | grep 9260`

> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter

or `sudo lshw | grep ntel -A 5 -B 3`

> *-usb:0
> description: Bluetooth wireless interface
> product: Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter
> vendor: Intel Corp.
> physical id: 5
> bus info: usb@3:5
> version: 0.02
> capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
> configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s`

While `sudo lshw -C network` only shows wired connections including the tethered phone I am using to submit this report.

Given the device isn't recognized, I think I need to make the driver available to the kernel, and I can confirm that I have the current driver version(s) available at `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-9260*`. Thus, I have tried to add iwlwifi to the kernel with `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` which successfully lists `lsmod | grep iwl`

> iwlwifi               450560  0
> cfg80211              974848  1 iwlwifi

But, this doesn't seem to do anything to solve the issue and upon reboot `lsmod | grep iwl` is blank.

Finally `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` doesn't fix anything.
If there is anything further I could do to fix this, I would be more than happy to give it a shot. Short of downgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: did you ever get this working, I have exactly this issue.

Comment: Actually no, I gave up later that day. Once I returned to it after a week, it just worked. Hopefully that's reproducible for others...